# How to reduce CPU utilization of tensorflow.keras.models.load_model to load a Tensorflow model saved in .h5 format?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to serve a Tensorflow model using `fastAPI` on an AKS pod. The model is saved in `.h5` format. Everything else is running fine.

However, when I am trying to import `load_model` module, the cluster is crashing due to high CPU utilization (100%).

`from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model` causes the pod to crash. When I comment the line out (and dependent lines), everything works fine and CPU utilization is around ~4%.

How can I load the model saved in the `.h5` format to use it only for inferencing? I am also open to saving it in a different format (other than `.h5`).

The resource limits for our AKS Pod:

```
CPU Limit - 1000 mc
CPU Request - 250 mc
Memory Limit - 500 MB
Memory Request - 250 MB
```

Comment: Just to double check my understanding, is the AKS pod crashing when importing the `load_model`, or when you load the .h5 file?

Comment: During importing `load_model` module itself.

Comment: Did you tried to import other functions from the `tensorflow.keras.models` to see if the problem persists or is only with the `load_model`? I mean, if you send `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`, AKS pod will still crashing? Another thing you can try (I dont know if is your case or not) is to save only the weights of your already trained model, and build your architecture again and load just the weights.

Comment: Still failing. `import tensorflow` is failing too